# My BD Writer is not working and crashes Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, crash, dvd, blu-ray

So I bought a new desktop PC with a BD Writer (Asus BW-16D1HT). The thing is that although reads DVDs, when a I try to install a game (Age of Mythology DVD ROM) it crashes Windows Explorer and do nothing. I've already install the game in my laptop and its working so I know it's not the optical disc. I've try this with other game and it happens the same thing.

Please help me out.

Comment: Please verify you can burn any video file to a DVD and play it.  I have the same drive, I don't have any of the problems you describe, I suspect a hardware issue.

Comment: I suspect you're not running the installer in compatibility mode. What windows are you using? Is your laptop win10 as well?

Comment: Hi to all of you. I bring news. I could also install it in my desktop. The problem is that when the DVD is installing you can't use any other app. I don't know why this happens. So is just that, I can't do anything else or it crushes. FYI, both my laptop and desktop have W10 but my laptop has DVD and my desktop BD. Thanks guys for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Age of Mythology discs use a Safedisc copy protection which is no longer supported on windows 10.

You can confirm if it's the SafeDisk protection by making an ISO copy of your DVD using the functional PC. Copy over the ISO file to the new dekstop and mount it. If it still crashes then the issue is the copy protection.

Solution 1: 
You can probably only run it in a virtual XP/7 environment with Safedsc enabled. Install the VM software of your choice and run either OS. Then install the game in said OS.

Solution 2: Get a No-CD "modifier". Highly un-recommended.

Solution 3: Buy it digitally. Steam has it. Even though you own it already:
https://store.steampowered.com/app/266840/